# Relating SVD of Real Matrix to SVDs of Matrix's Rows?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I have some real matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ with SVD $A = U S V^T$. If I splinter (probably not the correct mathematical term) the matrix into its rank-1 rows $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$ and compute the SVD of each row separately $A_i = u_i s_i v_i^T$, how do the singular values and singular vectors of the original matrix relate to the singular values and singular vectors of each row's SVD?

Edit: If $U \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}, S \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, I believe I can write the $i$th row vector of $A$ as

$$A_i = [\sum_{k=1}^{rank(A)} s_k U_{ik} V_{1k}, ..., \sum_{k=1}^K s_k U_{ik} V_{nk}]$$

Is that correct? If so, does that help?

Comment: the SVD of a row vector $A_i$ would just be $v_i=A_i^t, s_i=1, u_i=[1]$, unless i am missing something

Comment: I don't think so. $A_i$ isn't an orthonormal vector, but one could rectify that by normalizing the magnitude of $A_i$ and setting the singular value to that magnitude?

Comment: right of course, you would actually want $s_i=1/|A_i|$

Comment: I'm not sure. Wouldn't you want the singular value to restore the magnitude of the vector?

Comment: That is, if $v_i = A_i/||A_i||$, then $A_i \neq [1][\frac{1}{||A_i||}, 0, ..., 0] \frac{A_i}{||A_i||}$ right?

Comment: Regardless, I'd like the final answer to be expressed as a function of the original matrix's singular values and singular vectors $U, S, V$. So I need more specificity than the direction and norm of $A_i$

Comment: You've already found the SVD of that row. I wouldn't expect any nice connection with the SVD of the full matrix. For instance, the $i$th row of $A$ is the $i$th row of $U$ (transposed) times $SV^\top$; the $i$th row of $U$ has no tangible connection with the singular vectors (columns of $U$) since you are throwing away a bunch of components.

Comment: In order to examine properties of rows, I would consider the transpose. I am not sure what rows of matrices represent in the linear transforms they correspond to. Columns on the other hand are the result of the corresponding transform acting on domain's basis.